# ChartJS - why is there a visual difference when displaying the same dataset alone or with more datasets?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yydh6wse/)

i'm using ChartJS and i've encountered a bizarre issue i can't figure out. it'd be awesome if someone could point out what's wrong here..

i got 2 datasets

the first one is OK. when displayed individually or when displayed with the second dataset, it remains the same (it looks identical, toggle "both" and "first" in the demo)

unlike the first dataset, the second dataset looks different when it is displayed by itself in opposed to being displayed along with the first dataset. (click "second" and "both' in the demo)

as a byproduct of this behavior (i think), i've also noticed that the second dataset's first point y position is wrong. the value is `8` yet the y position is `0`. the first dataset also has `8` as its first data point and it is drawn correctly.

what am i missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll recommend you to set a minimum and maximum display value to the Y Axis like:

```
 yAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: true,
    drawTicks: false,
  },
  ticks: {
    min:0,
    max: 25
  }
}]
```

If its not done, it auto-scales to the minimum and maximum value of the datasets, and it can be different in each display mode.